# Jquery UI draggable changing the size of other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/M9paZ4Cni3srwK898CKq?p=preview) I have a div between two other divs. The div in the middle can be dragged up and down (with Jquery Draggable) to resize the height of the two other divs. However there's a strange behavior, the div that is dragged does not follow the mouse, and you can see two divider lines. How to fix this?

HTML

```
    <div id="top1"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="bottom1"></div>
```

Javascript

```
      var top1H, bottom1H;
      $( "#div1" ).draggable({
          axis: "y",
          start: function() {
              top1H = $("#top1").height();
              bottom1H = $("#bottom1").height();
            },
          drag: function(event,ui) {
              var shift = ui.position.top;
              $("#top1").height(top1H + shift);
              $("#bottom1").height(bottom1H - shift);
            }
        });
```

CSS

```
#div1 { 
  width:180px;
  height:6px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  cursor:ns-resize;
}
#top1{
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
}
#bottom1 {
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the effect you want by making some small changes to the height calculations.

Here's an updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YMrtRysLYFyrWsmdWtb3?p=preview)

The main change was to the height calculation:

```
$( "#div1" ).draggable({
  axis: "y",
  start: function(event, ui) {
    shiftInitial = ui.position.top;
    top1H = $("#top1").height();
    bottom1H = $("#bottom1").height();
  },
  drag: function(event,ui) {
    var shift = ui.position.top;
    $("#top1").height(top1H + shift - shiftInitial);
    $("#bottom1").height(bottom1H - shift + shiftInitial);
  }
});
```

[image]